# End of File (EOF) in C program

Tags: c, eof, getchar

I made a simple C program that needs to be finishing when the `EOF` character is entered (<kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> for windows) and should print:

- Passed if the grade is higher or equal to 5.
- Passed with High Pass if the grade is higher or equal to 8.
- Failed for any other case.

I use `getchar()` for user's inputs (grade in this case).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int grade;
    puts("Enter a grade\n");
    puts("Enter the EOF character to end input\n");

    while ((grade = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (grade >= 5) {
            puts("Passed");
            if (grade >= 8) {
                puts("with High Pass\n");
            }
        } else {
            puts("Failed\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that program isn't doing what is supposed to be doing and I would appreciate if you could help me find a solution.

Comment: Note that `EOF` is not a character, but a macro for the value returned by some functions when an end-of-file condition is encountered (or returned when there is an error in some cases).

Comment: what if the user enters 'A' instead of 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program does not function as expected for 2 reasons:

- bytes read from `stdin` are not numeric values: if the user type `1`, the program receives `'1'` which is the character value, not the numeric value. You can compute the numeric value of a digit character by subtracting the character value of `'0'`:

  ```
  int c = getchar();
  if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
      int grade = c - '0';
      /* you can now test the grade */
  ```
- You read standard input one byte at a time: it does not allow for grades that exceed `9`. If the user types `10`, you will be testing 2 grades and output `Failed!` twice.

Here is a alternate version with `scanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int grade;
    puts("Enter the grades\n");
    puts("Enter the EOF character to end input\n");

    while (scanf("%d", &grade) == 1) {
        if (grade >= 8) {
            puts("Passed with High Pass");
        } else
        if (grade >= 5) {
            puts("Passed");
        } else {
            puts("Failed\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Clear enough . Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

You get the ascii  code  of entered digit, not its value. Convert it to the number before comparition.

```
while ((grade = getchar()) != EOF) {
    getchar();  // flush the \n
    if (isdigit(grade))
    {
        int intgrade = grade - '0';

        if (intgrade >= 5) {
            puts("Passed");
            if (intgrade >= 8) {
                puts("with High Pass\n");
            }
        }
        else {
            puts("Failed\n");
        }
    }
    else printf("Wrong entry\n");
}

return 0;
```

Comment: You can make a simple cast for example: `int grade_as_int = (int)grade;`

Comment: @m.nachury - you can't . It does not convert `'1'` to integer 1. it assigns the `grade_as_int` the ascii code of grade.  All will pass will the "High Pass"

Comment: If you insert number longer than one digit, it flushes the second digit instead of `\n` so for `45` is output failed. Its wrong.

Comment: It is the answer for the question asked.

Comment: "45" is not a char and he wants use getchar().  @Filip Kočica be nicer - you are a very aggressive and unfriendly guy. I do not understand what you want to proof.

Comment: He is using `getchar` becouse asker isnt that expirienced and probably found that code somewhere, program has to correctly deal with all inputs, and `45` _is_ correct input.

Comment: @Filip Kočica so you can even use telepathy  to read from his brain. BTW you do not know the grading system (oh sorry you took it from his mind :) )

Comment: Ofc there is possibility that some user will insert number higher that `9`. Program has to correctly deal with it.

Comment: @Filip Kočica Are you trolling me? You do not know what that couple of lines are for. Maybe to test what the `getchar` is.

Comment: Talking to you is absolutely pointless. Just wanted to tell you that for input higher that `9` its wrong. Becouse OP wrote _grade is higher or equal to 8_, and numbers with more digits _are_ greater or equal to 8.

Comment: @FilipKočica I made this program to understand how getchar() and EOF work for a simple problem like this (grades). That's why i am not interested for inputs higher than 9.

Comment: But programs posted on SO should work in all cases and deal with all kind of inputs, no _just_ somehow work.

Comment: @DavidBowling Thanks for your advise , i will keep this in mind .

Comment: @David Bowling no. it has to answer or point to the answer to the question asked and nothing more. He did not ask: _how to safely enter number for the grade_ or _how to handle wrong inputs_ etc.

Comment: @David Bowling thanks God you and other much better coders than I am can always downvote me. EOD

Comment: @Kostas Kokkorogiannis the main issue you have is that getchar returns ascii codeof the symbol entered, nor the integer value represented by character ie '1' is 0x31 not 1. I think that you will understand that is you enter `345` you will get 3 consecutive reads + one read of '\n'

Comment: @David Bowling I did not write thay you did. There is enough other happy to do so :)

Comment: @PeterJ Thank you very much. :)